# Why LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean class is called "Local"?

Tags: java, spring

Spring has a class called LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean. Why is this class called "Local"? In what meaning is it local? Is there some RemoteEntityManagerFactoryBean class in Spring as well?

Comment: did you read api docs ?http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean.html

Comment: Yes, I did. I haven't found an answer there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont have an authoritative source, however I'm pretty sure that it is "Local" in that it is local to the spring application context used by the application.

Spring doesn't provide a Remote EMF, however other components such as application servers will. For instance JBoss AS (an open source J2EE app server) can manage JPA EMF's and will make it available to your application at runtime, eg over JNDI, refer [to the JBoss docs](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide#JPAReferenceGuide-Entitymanager)